# Pass async method to different class

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates

I have a method which looks like the following:

```
protected async Task<TModel> GetItemFromServerAsync(string id) { ... }
```

I want to pass this method to another class and execute it there.
I tried to use the Func keyword, but I'm not able to pass the method when I call the following method:

```
public async Task<List<TModel>> Import(Func<string, Task<TModel>> getEntityFromDatabase)
```

How can I call the GetItemFromServerAsync method within another class?

Comment: What is passing method? You can create object of class & call that method

Comment: Just tried it. Everything work for me. Can you give more details? I passed `GetItemFromServerAsync` one class to another class method `Import`

Comment: Just create an instance of another class and call your method like `await myClassInstance.GetItemFromServerAsync(myID);`

Comment: @ershoaib that's what I wanted to avoid, because the whole structure is much more complex and this would require a very big refactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` on it's own does not change the interface, so it works just fine. Here is an example:

```
void SendMyMethod()
{
    MyMethod2(MyMethod);
}

async Task<string> MyMethod(int a)
{
    return "5";
}

void MyMethod2(Func<int, Task<string>> func)
{
    func(5);
}
```

So it has be something else that does not work. Maybe you should post your code and the error that you get.

Comment: I did it in the exacly same way as you, but I get the error: "Cannot use a method group as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: You should probably post more of your code, so that we can see what are you doing, perhaps there is something else we are not taking into account here.

Comment: I found the problem. I had a second parameter I removed in my question because I thought it doesn't matter. But now I found out that I passed a value of type dynamic and therefore it had problems with my second parameter. Now I cast the dynamic type to the correct type and it is working exactly as described by you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with `async` - I think your issue is that `Import` doesnt know what `TModel` is.

You haven't specified `TModel` anwhere, but I assume its defined on a class containing `GetItemFromServerAsync`

```
public class DataAccess<TModel>
{
    public async Task<TModel> GetItemFromServerAsync(string id)
    {
        return default(TModel); // just to make it compile, I assume you do some data access here or something
    }
}
```

Then on the calling side, you need to specify `TModel` as part of the method (But you don't have to explicitly name it, it will be inferred):

```
async Task<List<TModel>> Import<TModel>(Func<string, Task<TModel>> getEntityFromDatabase)
{
    //...///
}
```

And the calling code should be along the lines of:

```
var da = new DataAccess<SomeType>();
var result = Import(da.GetItemFromServerAsync); // would be a list of "SomeType"
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OUUJG52678

Comment: Worth noting that the problem seem to have nothing to do with `async`, but with the generic. So the question title is a bit off.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik yes, Ive improved answer to be clear on that point.

Comment: @Jamiec I defined for both of my classes that TModel is of type BaseModel. It should be known in both classes. I'll try you approach, thanks!